# How do I modify the behavior of specific payable function calls with my token in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, cryptocurrency, erc20

Say I want to make it so certain wallets can never, ever receive my token, or maybe so that interactions with a specific, known malicious contract, or broken functions on an otherwise working contract on chain always revert. How do I go about doing this?

In my specific case, I would like to make it so that for a period after deployment, but before a hardcoded unix timestamp, people can add or remove liquidity to a uniswap pool, but no swaps can occur, so that the price stays constant while everyone adds liquidity, until the timestamp passes and swaps are then able to occur, and so that they can all safely remove their liquidity from the pool if something goes wrong before the timestamp passes with no impermanent loss.

Answer (score 0):

For the "blacklist" functionality, you could maintain a mapping containing the blacklisted accounts. Then whenever a transfer of your token occurs, you can `require` that the address not be in the blacklist, otherwise the transfer reverts. You could also add a function to "un-blacklist" an account, if you so wished.

As for the second point - i'm curious as to how you're defining the 'price' of your token if no swaps can occur, and what incentivises anyone to add liquidity under that arrangement?

Comment: Assuming I deploy the token and I am the only holder, I can add the token to uniswap at a certain token:ETH ratio initially, anyone adding liquidity before buys and sells would have to add in the same ratio, or at the same price.